# Java - Using JavaMail to send and receive S/MIME messages

Tags: java, encryption, jakarta-mail, mime, smime

JavaMail makes it easy to send MIME messages.  How can I use it to send S/MIME? (I know JavaMail-Crypto is designed to solve this, but it seems incomplete and abandoned).  I'd like to send and receive, encrypt and sign, decrypt and verify, using X.509 certs.

Comment: Checkout this github project: https://github.com/markenwerk/java-utils-mail-smime

Answer (score 0):

[Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) is the place to start.

Comment: Maybe someone wanted me to copy all of the Bouncy Castle instructions here so that you didn't have to go read the Bouncy Castle web site?